# ROC curve plotting

Tags: python, size, one-hot-encoding, indices

Trying to plot an ROC Curve with a dataset of size 1200 having 179 columns(as features) using SVM gives the following following error :

'Too many indices for the array'

Code:

```
 from sklearn.svm import SVC
 svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')

 svm = svclassifier.fit(X_train, Y_train).decision_function(X_test)

 Y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)

 ns_predt = [0 for _ in range(len(Y_test))]

 Y_predt = Y_pred[:,1]
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last) IndexError
<ipython-input-92-62de12967d46> in <module>
----> 1 Y_predt = Y_pred[:,1]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: show working code, to be able to reproduce the error

Comment: Y_pred has a different shape than you're expecting, which is why your Y_pred[:,1] doesn't work. Could you print "Y_pred.shape"?

Comment: Y_test is 0,1 labels for 480 instances. Y_test.shape and Y_pred.shape gives output as (480,0), (480,0).Y_pred according to the code above gives output like : [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 
 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
 ........ 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0].  @ZarakiKenpachi

Comment: Y_pred.shape is (480,0) @Rens

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting has to do with the requested and available indices in "Y_pred[:,1]".
You're requesting all rows (the colon ':') of column 1 (with Python's zero-indexing, that's actually the 2nd column). However, Y_pred is a numpy 1D-array (i.e. no columns).

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in `ns_predt = [0 for _ in range(len(Y_test))]` nor with `Y_predt = Y_pred[:,1]`, so I can't give you an alternative. But the issue is clear: you're requesting columns that don't exist.

The issue can be easily replicated with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pdb
from sklearn.svm import SVC

print('Creating fake data..')
X_train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
Y_train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('E'))

X_test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
Y_test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('E'))

print('Initializing classifier')
svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear')

print('Training the model')
svm = svclassifier.fit(X_train, Y_train).decision_function(X_test)

print('Predicting outcome')
Y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)

print('... ? ...')
ns_predt = [0 for _ in range(len(Y_test))]
try:
    Y_predt = Y_pred[:,1]
except:
    print('I failed...')
    pdb.set_trace()
```